# AES decryption with invalid length

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have server-client. Server encrypt message and send to client. 
Client want to decrypt, but program is crash and error say: *Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.*

Here is code, where I listener server.

```
while (true)
{
    if (tok.CanRead) 
    {
        tok = client.GetStream();
        int buffSize = 0;
        byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
        tok.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
        RijndaelManaged AesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged();
        AesEncryption.KeySize = 256; // 192, 256
        AesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
        AesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        AesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        string keyStr = "cGFzc3dvcmQAAAAAAAAAAA==";
        string ivStr = "cGFzc3dvcmQAAAAAAAAAAA==";
        byte[] ivArr = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
        byte[] keyArr = Convert.FromBase64String(ivStr);
        AesEncryption.IV = ivArr;
        AesEncryption.Key = keyArr;
        ICryptoTransform decrypto = AesEncryption.CreateDecryptor();
        inStream = decrypto.TransformFinalBlock(inStream, 0, inStream.Length); //here is error

        string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
        readdata = "" + returndata;
        msg();
    }
}
```

How can I fix that length?.

Comment: Using a hard-coded IV defeats the purpose of CBC.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET API is build around streams. Try and use the [CryptoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) API instead, initialized with an [`AesCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [TransformFinalBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform.transformfinalblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should only be used for low level access, and only for the last bytes of the ciphertext.

Quote:

> TransformFinalBlock is a special function for transforming the last block or a partial block in the stream. It returns a new array that contains the remaining transformed bytes. A new array is returned, because the amount of information returned at the end might be larger than a single block when padding is added.

Comment: Sorry, previous answer was indeed incorrect, confused client & server code.

Comment: It's same. `string returndata = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();` //here is error. I use DESCryptoServiceProvider and CryptoStream with MemoryStream and StreamReader.

Comment: DES? A string function? Why? Don't you have `AesCryptoServiceProvider`?

Comment: Is the same. Error on `ReadToEnd` Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.

Comment: Can you compare the ciphertext at yhe client and server? How many bytes? Whats with the strange buffer size? Where is the loop required to tead the stream?

Comment: I have fix size: `new byte[10025]` on both same. loop is in the start of my function: `while(true)` using. Without this decryption this work. I got messages normaly every time.

Comment: I guess you need to find a good example for reading the stream. Having the loop around the streams won't work. Plenty of examples on this site.